# Timestamp many2many?

Tags: django, many-to-many, timestamp, models

I have the following Abstract:

```
class A:
    clientname ...
    logs = models.ManyToManyField(B, blank=True, null=True)

class B.
    message ...
    timestamp =  models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timestamp = datetime.now()
        super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, if a message is saved I want it to have a timestamp, always. And I do not want to change the many2many relationship. Is this possible? And if It is how would I go about writing it?

UPDATE:

my view

```
def log(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        log, created = B.objects.get_or_create(message=request.POST['message'])
        client = \
            A.objects.get(clientname=request.POST['clientname'])
        client.logs.add(log)
        return HttpResponse(content="OK", mimetype="text/plain", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(content="Failed", mimetype="text/plain", status=400)
```

RESOLUTON:
I did it, this is kind of a workaround:

```
def log(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time = datetime.now()
        log, created = \
            Log.objects.get_or_create(message=request.POST['message'], \
            timestamp=time)
        client = \
            Thinclient.objects.get(hostname=request.POST['clientname'])
        client.logs.add(log)
        return HttpResponse(content="OK", mimetype="text/plain", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(content="Failed", mimetype="text/plain", status=400)
```

UPDATE:

No actually that wasn't what I wanted either because this will create new message instances even if the message is the same

Comment: use "get_or_create" if your message is the same as last, it will not add

Comment: where exactly do you want me to add that, I'm using it for the message part?! I don't want him/her/user to create a client if it does not exist, that would be troublesome

Comment: No,because you use "get_or_create" in B, so if the "messages" is the same as one before,then it will do nothing, only get the log,if you want to update the timestamp of this log,add log.timestamp = datetime.now() log.save()

Comment: also like this "log=Log.objects.create(message=request.POST['message'],
            timestamp=time)"

Comment: if you want to add timestamp only when messages is the same,you should add another table to save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add save() to the class B

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.timestamp = datetime.now()
    super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks however, it still doesn't save 2 instances (message1=test, timestamp=10:07, and message2=test, timestamp=10:8) of message with different timestamps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTimeField` with `auto_now` argument:

`timestamp = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`

More about this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

Comment: Already tried that and it doesn't work. It only ever saves one timestamp. I do POST: message=test, name=test and i get a timestamp, so far so good however when i do the same post a minute later it still shows the timestamp of the first POST